# jquery each method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a website and this particular section requires the user to enter their details in a form. What I am trying to achieve is the following;

If the user hits the submit button and any fields are empty, I want a span element, which is initially set to CSS display none, to show up for each respective input field which has not been filled.

However, nothing seems to be happening when I click on the button. When I go to the console, it does not display any error message.

Can someone please assist? Many thanks.

HTML:

```
<!-- START OF 'YOUR DETAILS' FORM-->

<section>


    <div class="container">

        <h3>Step 3: Your Details</h3>

        <!-- SLIDE-IN DIV TO REPRESENT DAY PASS -->

        <div class="row chosenmembership">

        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="yourdetails">

            <form action="" method="">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Email is required!</span>
                </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="name" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Name is required!</span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="number">Contact Number:</label>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="Contact Number" id="number" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Contact Number is required!</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="postcode">Post Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" id="postcode" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Post Code is required!</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="dob" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
DOB is required!</span>
                    </div>

                            </form>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="CONTINUE">
                    </div>




        </div>

    </div>

    </div>


</section>

<!-- END OF YOUR DETAILS FORM -->
```

JS / JQUERY:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
        var $formValues = $(".your-details");
        var $warning = $(".warnings");
        $($formValues).each(function(index){
            if ($(this).val("")){
            $($warning[index]).css("display","block");
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: your variable names are really confusing. you should consider renaming  $formValues to formValues and $warning to warning. It make it hard to read.

Comment: no need to create a NEW jQuery object with `$($formValues).each(function(index){` just use the one you have. `$formValues.each(function(index){`

Comment: @demon a lot of people like to prefix jquery selectors with dollar signs. I personally hate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors are kind of redundant, keep the form from submission and show the warnings when any are empty seems to be your intent.

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  $(".your-details").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).val() =="") {
      e.preventDefault();// no submit if not filled out
      $(this).next('.warning').css("display", "block");// next sibling show
    }
  });
});
```

Thought about this for a bit and believe you might handle the form submit instead

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.warning').css("display", "none");// hide in case they fix input values
  $(this).find(".your-details").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).val() =="") {
      $(this).next('.warning').css("display", "block");// next sibling show
    }
  });
});
```

Alternately you might use a filter.

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.warning').css("display", "none");// hide in case they fix input values
  var emptyInputs = $(this).find(".your-details")
    .filter(function() {
        return ($(this).val() =="");
    });
  if(!!emptyInputs) {
     e.preventDefault();
     emptyInputs.next('.warning').css("display", "block"); 
   }
});
```

Comment: Note if you want to hide the warnings first, simply insert it before the loop as `$('.warning').css("display", "none");`

Answer (score 2):

When your running this code `$($formValues).each(function(index){if ($(this).val("")){` console.log(this) and see in which context your function is running, the issue is that every time you write a function declaration it creates a new `this` context and thus the previous `this` is lost.

Comment: Function declaration itself, doesnt change value of `this`. It depends how you invoke that function. `$(this)` in his code refers to the right value.

Comment: @jimmy118 So correcting warnings variable name did help?

Comment: Yes, now warnings appears after submit

Answer (score 0):

Except typo, there was one  problem more, you are actually setting value, instead of checking it:   `if ($(this).val(""))` If you change it, and fix typo, something like this should work. Simplified, your code could look like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
        var $formValues = $(".your-details");

        $($formValues).each(function(index){
            if ($(this).val()==''){

           $(".warning").eq(index).css("display","block");
            }
            else {
             $(".warning").eq(index).css("display","none");
            }
        })
    })
```

Demo:

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
        var $formValues = $(".your-details");
        
        $($formValues).each(function(index){
            if ($(this).val()==''){
         
           $(".warning").eq(index).css("display","block");
            }
            else {
             $(".warning").eq(index).css("display","none");
            }
        })
    })
```

```css
.warning {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- START OF 'YOUR DETAILS' FORM-->

<section>


    <div class="container">

        <h3>Step 3: Your Details</h3>

        <!-- SLIDE-IN DIV TO REPRESENT DAY PASS -->

        <div class="row chosenmembership">

        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="yourdetails">

            <form action="" method="">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Email is required!</span>
                </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="name" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Name is required!</span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="number">Contact Number:</label>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="Contact Number" id="number" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Contact Number is required!</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="postcode">Post Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" id="postcode" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Post Code is required!</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="dob" class="form-control your-details">
                    <span class="warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
DOB is required!</span>
                    </div>

                            </form>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="CONTINUE">
                    </div>




        </div>

    </div>

    </div>


</section>

<!-- END OF YOUR DETAILS FORM -->
```

P.S. You can keep your: `$($warning[index])` vars, but you should hide warnings, anyway (else block), if field is not empty.